# Can I combine all of this code into a function or is this the only way to do it?

Tags: jquery

This Jquery code makes the arrows on my page scroll through the page. I feel like there's a better and shorter way to do this.

```
//Functions that make the arrows on the page scroll through the page.
$("#arrow1").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#aboutMe").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});

$("#arrow2").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#skillsPart").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});

$("#arrow3").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#contactMe").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});

$("#arrow4").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#topPart").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Based on your actual markup you can reduce it to just one function, please include that

Comment: yup. certainly possible to write clean code.

Comment: Do you have to use those exact ID's? I have a 6 line solution, but I changed the `.offset()` elements id names.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a reusable function which would allow you to easily add more click handlers by just adding the element and the elemnt you want to scroll to into the `els` array

```
var main = $('html, body');
function handleClick(el, scrollToEl) {
    el.click(function() {
    main.animate({
      scrollTop: scollToEl.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  })
}

var els = [
  [$('#arrow1'), $("#aboutMe")],
  [$('#arrow2'), $("#skillsPart")],
  [$('#arrow3'), $("#contactMe"],
  [$('#arrow4'), $("#topPart")]
];

els.forEach(function(el){
    handleClick(el[0], el[1]);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I've got an answer that might not be what you are looking for, but still something I guess...

```js
$("#arrow1,#arrow2,#arrow3,#arrow4").click(function() {
  var a1 = $("#aboutMe").offset().top,
    a2 = $("#skillsPart").offset().top,
    a3 = $("#contactMe").offset().top,
    a4 = $("#topPart").offset().top;
  switch ($(this).attr("id") {
    case "arrow1":
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: a1
      }, 1000);
      break;
    case "arrow2":
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: a2
      }, 1000);
      break;
    case "arrow3":
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: a3
      }, 1000);
      break;
    case "arrow4":
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: a4
      }, 1000);
      break;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mn6184p1/2/

Comment: hah. with no comments or whitespace, it's still more lines than the original. hint: `$('html, body').animate({` doesn't need to be in the event handler more than once.

Comment: @KevinB yeah, not the best way to do it :-|

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mn6184p1/3/, and if the content doesn't change, you can move the map outside of the handler. and you can replace that complex selector with .arrow after giving the elements all the same `arrow` classname.